# Determining which R architectures are installed

Tags: r

How does one determine which architectures are supported by an installation of R? On a standard windows install, one may look for the existence of R_HOME/bin/*/R.exe where * is the architecture (typically i386 or x64). On a standard mac install from CRAN, there are no subdirectories.

I can query R for the default architecture using something like:

```
$ R --silent -e "sessionInfo()[[1]][[2]]"
> sessionInfo()[[1]][[2]]
[1] "x86_64"
```

but how do I know on mac/linux whether any sub-architectures are installed, and if so what they are?

Answer (score 4):

`R.version`, `R.Version()`, `R.version.string`, and `version` provide detailed information about the version of R running.

Update, based on a better understanding of the question.  This isn't a complete solution, but it seems you can get fairly close via a combination of the following commands:

```
# get all the installed architectures
arch <- basename(list.dirs(R.home('bin'), recursive=FALSE))
# handle different operating systems
if(.Platform$OS.type == "unix") {
  arch <- gsub("exec","",arch)
  if(arch == "")
    arch <- R.version$arch
} else {  # Windows
  # any special handling
}
```

Note that this won't work if you've built R from source and installed the different architectures in various different places. See [2.6 Sub-architectures](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#Sub_002darchitectures) of the [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html) manual for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Sys.info()` you have a lot of information on your system. 
May be it can help here

```
Sys.info()["machine"]
 machine 
"x86_64"
```

**EDIT**

One workaround to have all architecture possible is to download [log files](http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/) from the Rstudio mirror, it's not complete but it's good estimate of what you need.

```
start <- as.Date('2012-10-01')
today <- as.Date('2013-07-01')

all_days <- seq(start, today, by = 'day')
year <- as.POSIXlt(all_days)$year + 1900
urls <- paste0('http://cran-logs.rstudio.com/', year, '/', all_days, '.csv.gz')
files <- file.path("/tmp", basename(urls))

list_data <- lapply(files, read.csv, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
data <- do.call(rbind, list_data)

str(data)
## 'data.frame':    10694506 obs. of  10 variables:
##  $ date     : chr  "2012-10-01" "2012-10-01" "2012-10-01" "2012-10-01" ...
##  $ time     : chr  "00:30:13" "00:30:15" "02:30:16" "02:30:16" ...
##  $ size     : int  35165 212967 167199 21164 11046 42294 435407 326143 119459 868695 ...
##  $ r_version: chr  "2.15.1" "2.15.1" "2.15.1" "2.15.1" ...
##  $ r_arch   : chr  "i686" "i686" "x86_64" "x86_64" ...
##  $ r_os     : chr  "linux-gnu" "linux-gnu" "linux-gnu" "linux-gnu" ...
##  $ package  : chr  "quadprog" "lavaan" "formatR" "stringr" ...
##  $ version  : chr  "1.5-4" "0.5-9" "0.6" "0.6.1" ...
##  $ country  : chr  "AU" "AU" "US" "US" ...
##  $ ip_id    : int  1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 3 ...

unique(data[["r_arch"]])
##  [1] "i686"      "x86_64"    NA          "i386"      "i486"     
##  [6] "i586"      "armv7l"    "amd64"     "000000"    "powerpc64"
## [11] "armv6l"    "sparc"     "powerpc"   "arm"       "armv5tel"
```

Comment: ...but `Sys.info()` isn't supported on all platforms.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I just tried on an old machine with windows8 and it works. In the help file they didn't mention it or I'm wrong.

Comment: That may not be in the Windows documentation, but it's in the documentation in my Unbuntu install. It's in the first sentence of the *Details* section, "This function is not implemented on all R platforms...".

Comment: I'm asking specifically about finding all architectures. This only gives the architecture of the version or R running. I already know how to get that (see question).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks I see now..I read it in linux but was focused on *(Under Windows, it is obtained by Windows system
     calls and the last three values are the same.)*

Comment: @IanFellows: be careful. `Sys.info` provides details about the _system_ R is running on.  It doesn't tell you anything about how R was built.

Comment: @IanFellows I see, you want ALL possible architecture where R can run.

Comment: @dickoa Interesting code, but you have again misunderstood the question. R can have multiple architectures installed on top of each other within the same R_HOME directory. The question that I am asking is: How can I get a list of all architectures supported by a particular installation of R? Not which is the default architecture, or what is a list of all conceivable architectures.

Comment: @IanFellows I finally get it (was long though :] ). Don't know but curious of a possible answer to this question. Thanks

Comment: On a mac there is a .../bin/ directory that you could probably locate and run a list.files()